# FindOneAndDelete on MERN stack would return successful but the data is still in database?

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, async-await, fetch

I am trying to use `findOneAndDelete` method in "mongoose" on my `DELETE` endpoint using "Expressjs" as my server and "reactjs" handling a fetch API in a try-catch to delete the selected data.
I am getting a 200 but the delete result json brings an n=0 games deleted and data is not getting deleted from my database. Here is the code:

endpoint:

```
    router.delete('/trivia/:name', async (req, res) => {
        const gameToDelete = req.params.name;
        try {
            const deleteQuery = games.Trivia.findOneAndDelete({ name: gameToDelete });
            const deleteResult = await deleteQuery.deleteOne();
            console.log("Deleting a game from database", deleteResult);
            res.send(deleteResult);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Failed to delete trivia", gameToDelete);
            res.status(500).send({ error: error.code, message: "Something went wrong, I couldn't delete your game" });
        }
    });
```

React fetch request:

```
    async function onDelete(game) {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(`/game/trivia/:${game}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
            body: null,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
          });

        } catch (error) {
          console.error("error", error);
        };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue actually was with : in fetching the delete request!
I had to correct

```
          const res = await fetch(`/game/trivia/:${game}`,
```

and put

```
          const res = await fetch(`/game/trivia/${game}`,
```

instead